# Apache reverse proxy with digest auth prevents stylesheets from Amazon S3

Tags: apache, amazon-s3, stylesheet, reverse-proxy, digest-authentication

I have a site that uses apache reverse proxy to combine an old IIS system with some new rails functionality (same database).  This works fine.

For staging I have created a beta site same as above except that I use ip address and digest-authorization to only allow developers access.  This works fine for ip addresses.

However, when I use digest-authorization my reverse proxied /stylesheets folder (which points to an Amazon S3 bucket) is blocked with an error like the following:

```
InvalidArgumentUnsupported Authorization TypeDigest username="danv", realm="BETA-ACCESS", nonce="ZiudHuLlBAA=d9fa13adaa4f0bd37e3faa7b30ed6bd60a5570b2", uri="/stylesheets/default/screen.css", algorithm=MD5, response="7e1bc11912474647756537bb0bd3e488", qop=auth, nc=00000007, cnonce="ed4a08fc70364cb9"Authorization0E3F4E27386E0A00BTZfZ5Uv4PwuMzOCoIYhorPEuPOdNusLZjTDowqlZXImxZ0bLjt22B9Y5v7wc8+4
```

I have searched the web but cannot find anything about this behavior.

Here are the relevant parts of the virtual host file:

```
# IP and DIGEST ACCESS
<Proxy *>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Include "D:\wamp\admin-allow.inc"
    AuthType Digest
    # realm associated with digest passwd
    AuthName "BETA-ACCESS"
    AuthDigestDomain /
    AuthUserFile "D:/wamp/digest"
    Require valid-user
    Satisfy Any
</Proxy>

# Reverse proxy pointing to CNAME that points to:
#  http://lib.decdynamics.com.s3.amazonaws.com/stylesheets
ProxyPass /stylesheets http://lib.decdynamics.com/stylesheets
ProxyPassReverse /stylesheets http://lib.decdynamics.com/stylesheets
```

Here is an URL showing direct access to a stylesheet:
    http://lib.decdynamics.com/stylesheets/default/screen.css

Here the same stylesheet accessed via digest-authorization (of course login required):
    http://beta.decdynamics.com/stylesheets/default/screen.css

What I am doing wrong?

Is it possible to exclude the /stylesheets folder from authorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks **drco** for the inspiration.

I decided to create a working example based on my real website (domain names and ip addresses are not real).

Note I had to use Location elements to isolate the /stylesheets, /images and /javascript folders. In future I will use a single /assets folder to DRY this up a bit.

I have a WAMP based apache server acting as reverse proxy to blend Windows IIS server subfolders with a linux based RAILS server with RAILS assets coming from Amazon S3.  Now when I do development with this site it is protected using Digest Authorization.  Which also allows me the ability to let a small number of clients directly access the beta.

```
#========================
# B E T A . E X A M P L E . C O M
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  ServerName    beta.example.com
  ServerAlias   www.beta.example.com
  DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www_proxy"
  ErrorLog "D:/wamp/logs/beta.example.com-error.log"
  CustomLog "D:/wamp/logs/beta.example.com-access.log" combined

  ProxyRequests Off
  <Proxy *>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Include "D:\wamp\admin-allow.inc"
    AuthType Digest
    # realm associated with digest passwd
    AuthName "BETA-ACCESS"
    AuthDigestDomain /
    AuthUserFile "D:/wamp/digest"
    Require valid-user
    Satisfy Any
  </Proxy>

  # I I S
  ProxyPass /ddaps http://localhost:8104/ddaps
  ProxyPassReverse /ddaps http://localhost:8104/ddaps

  ProxyPass /admin http://localhost:8104/admin
  ProxyPassReverse /admin http://localhost:8104/admin

  ProxyPass /themes http://localhost:8104/themes
  ProxyPassReverse /themes http://localhost:8104/themes

  # RAIL ASSETS
  ProxyPass /stylesheets http://lib.example.com/stylesheets
  ProxyPassReverse /stylesheets http://lib.example.com/stylesheets
  <Location /stylesheets>
    RequestHeader unset Authorization
  </Location>

  ProxyPass /images http://lib.example.com/images
  ProxyPassReverse /images http://lib.example.com/images
  <Location /images>
    RequestHeader unset Authorization
  </Location>

  ProxyPass /javascripts http://lib.example.com/javascripts
  ProxyPassReverse /javascripts http://lib.example.com/javascripts
  <Location /javascripts>
    RequestHeader unset Authorization
  </Location>

  # R A I L S
  ProxyPass / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8104/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8104/

</VirtualHost>
```

.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your proxy is sending the `Authorization` header to S3 and S3 responds with that error. This is because S3 uses the same `Authorization` header to authorize API requests and it does not support basic or digest authentication on it's own.

Do a test towards a local backend and verify what request headers are being sent by the proxy. If the `Authorization` header is indeed present, rewrite the request on the proxy to remove it before it's sent to the S3 backend.

Comment: I tried a local back and it works, so it is definitely S3. However, I am not sure how to examine the headers.
Also, I am not sure how to rewrite the headers. If it is not too much could you provide examples or point me to the appropriate documentation?

Comment: I took a look at this for removing or unsetting headers:

  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html

But I am still not sure how to view the headers sent by apache to s3.  Unless we are talking about something like tcpdump, which I have tried before but its a bit much for me since I have lttle experience with it.